# How do I identify, characterize and detect if trusted CAs compromised?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority

What is the best approach to use in identifying, characterizing and detecting compromised CAs? I do not mean an invalid certificate or invalid CA that can be identified by an X.509 during validation process. I am looking for a tool/approach that can identify and detect “trusted CA that is actually compromised. For example the cause of compromisation like attacker Impersonate or compromise CA key and try to issue fraudulent certificate/ fake CRL.

A part from existing methods such as CT, key pinning, DANE  etc which partly address some issues related to CA compromised.

I there a way from method like Blockchain, Machine learning or any role based approach can be used to first identify, characterize and detect if trusted CA really compromised?

Comment: Isn't CRL enough? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list

Comment: It is typically not possible for a consumer of certificates to detect when a certificate has been issued fraudulently.

Comment: CRL is issued by CA what about if CA get compromised or attacked? therefore likely can also issue a fake CRL. The method i am looking at how to detect or identify if CA really compromise due to impersonation attack or violation of policies. e.g approaches from the side of formal method, machine learning or blockchain or any role based approach suitable to use in identifying or detecting trusted CAs compromised.  I hope the points are clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ... like Blockchain ...

CT is already basically the same idea, i.e. a public list of all the certificates issued by a CA.

Also, the actual problem is not if a CA is compromised. The problem is if a CA issues certificates for sites which it is not supposed to do, no matter if this is because of a compromise, change in ownership and policy or bugs. [Certificate transparancy](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/) provides a public record of the certificates a CA has issued. [Certification Authority Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) provides a way for the domain owner to specify which CA is allowed to issue certificates for this domain - which then could be checked against CT records. Certificate pinning and public key pinning provides a way to narrow down at the client which exact certificate, public key or CA to expect for the certificate.

> ... which partly address some issues related to CA compromised.

I'm not sure if we actually need yet another technology or if we should use existing ones more extensively. It is impossible to tell if a CA issued fraudulent certificates unless it is clear what it is supposed to do and what not in the first place. As long as domain owners don't restrict which CA can issue certificates, any public CA can actually do. Sure, one could use human crafted or automatically crafted heuristics (i.e. machine learning) to predict what the domain owners might want based on previous behavior, but this will always lead to false positives which need to be somehow addressed.